# Hadoop name node format says "JAVA_HOME" not set

Tags: linux, hadoop

**Machine:** Linux Santiago

**Hadoop Version:** Apache hadoop 2.7.1

**Mode Of Installation:** Pseudo Distributed

**Done:** I downloaded the tar file and just extracted

**Checks:** I just set my JAVA_HOME in bashrc file and checked by echoing JAVA_HOME. It works.

**Stmt which caused error:** bin/hadoop namenode -format

**Error:** JAVA_HOME is not set

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Note down the following things

1) Set JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh

2) For newbie, don't forget to `export JAVA_HOME`

Then Formatting will be successful.